# Force immediate load of SVG file and icons

Tags: html, svg

I have a web app that makes multiple API calls to a back-end server, some of which can take a few seconds to pull data.  Unfortunately, an SVG file I created (7.5kB for multiple SVGs) gets stuck in a queue behind those other APIs and icons much longer to show up that I'd like.

I look at the Chrome developer console and see that the vast majority of the load time is due to waiting in the queue.

I load my SVGs in-line in the HTML as follows:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 58 58">
    <use xlink:href="/static/logos/my-icons.svg#filter"></use>
</svg>
```

I have about 30 of these types of links, but the console shows the file is only being downloaded once.

How can I make sure these load as soon as the rest of the HTML does?

**EDIT**

Clarification based on @Kaiido's comment - the `<script>` method loaded the file nearly instantaneously (thank you), but the file was then loaded a second time (and still waited) to actually show the SVGs.  So really, I'm looking for a way to load the SVGs immediately as soon as the SVG file is downloaded - preferably before all else.

Comment: `<script>fetch('/static/logos/my-icons.svg')</script>` or wait that the page has loaded before doing your API calls.

Comment: @kaiido - thanks for that, but please see my edit to the question.

Comment: Your server doesn't send the correct Cache headers? Or you disabled cache from your Netwok panel?

Comment: Don't even know what you're talking about... but you might be on to something.